# c# winforms binding the properties of a ListBox SelectedItem

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

So I have a listbox and a class. This class is called 'Mission' and has three properties: Name, IsStarted and IsCompleted.

I have used a BindingList and set the datasource of the Listbox to that BindingList. This works fine, no problems so far.

What I don't know how to do (and I hope it's possible) is to bind the properties IsStarted and IsCompleted to two CheckBoxes, so that if I change which Mission is selected, those CheckBoxes will change to reflect the properties of the SelectedItem.

I appreciate I can do this by using the event of SelectedItemChanged on the ListBox, but I would like to have a two way binding so that if I were to check or uncheck the CheckBoxes, the data in the class would change.

Comment: Hi FaithfullLearner, what you need is to to work with the 2 checkboxes individually. So depending on the checkboxes (if checked or not) you will set your combobox and based on your combobox selected value you have to set accordingly the checkboxes.

Comment: You don't need events, also you don't need two-way data binding. You need simple data binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use events, it's enough to use data binding:

```
missionsListBox.DataSource = bindingList;
missionsListBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
isStartedCheckBox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bindingList, "IsStarted");
isCompletedCheckBox.DataBindings.Add("Checked", bindingList, "IsCompleted")
```

This way, the `ListBox` will act as an index for mission objects and it shows a list of missions. When you select an item, it shows values of `IsStarted` and `IsCompleted` in corresponding check box controls and you can change those values for selected item using check boxes.

Comment: I'm dealing with another problem: Instead of checkboxes in this situation I need to bind the selected item of the listbox to another listbox and be able to change stuff in the second listbox as well.

Let's say the first listbox contains a list of racing cars and the second one list of racers in that cars and I need to add/remove cars and also add/remove/edit individual racers.

Comment: I created question to this comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70940851/c-sharp-winforms-bind-listbox-selecteditem-to-another-listbox