# listBox filled with objects

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, list, object

So I have a class called `Person`. Each Person can have a `Name`, `Age` and `Email`. And I have about 50 Person objects stored in a list called `PersonList`. Which I defined like this:

```
List<Person> PersonList = new List<Person>();
```

The array looks something like this:

```
PersonList = {
    { 
        name: 'John',
        age: 30,
        email: 'John@email.com'
    },
    { 
        name: 'Bill',
        age: 55,
        email: 'Bill@email.com'
    }
}
```

I then loop through this and add each of their `Name` in to a ListBox:

```
foreach (var Person in PersonList)
{
    ListBox.Items.Add(Person.Name);
}
```

**Please note: All names are unique.**

What I want to do now, is that when I select a name in the ListBox, I want their Name, Age and Email to be displayed in a label called Label1. Currently, I accomplish this by looping through the PersonList and checking for a name that matches the selected ListBox item's text.

```
private void ListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var Person in PersonList)
    {
        if (Person.Name == ListBox.SelectedItem.ToString())
        {
            Label1.Text = "Name: " + Person.Name + Environment.NewLine +
                          "Age: " + Person.Age + Environment.NewLine +
                          "Email: " + Person.Email;
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but is this the correct way of doing it? I feel like constantly looping through the PersonList to compare names could be bad for the performance. What if PersonList contained thousands of objects?

I also wonder if there is a better way to insert all the `Person.Name` in to the ListBox? Or is looping the way to go? I know about AddRange, but can I do that on just the Person.Name somehow? **Note: I only want to add their names in to the ListBox.**

What would you do?

Comment: It's better to use data-binding. Take a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43699718/3110834). Also using a `BindingList<Person>` would be better than `List<Person>`.

Comment: Not quite the correct way. - Add a ToString override to your class. Then you can add the  instances themselves instead of just the Names. And you can cast the selected object back to Person.

Comment: Are you using Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will look it up. I'm using Windows Forms @Fruchtzwerg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fill the listbox directly with the list, and the selection of the item can be done in 3 ways, see the code:

```
  public class Pessoa
    {
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Nome.ToString();
        }

    }
    List<Pessoa> lista = new List<Pessoa>();
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lista.Add(new Pessoa() { Nome = "Rovann1", Email = "Teste1@Teste.com" });
        lista.Add(new Pessoa() { Nome = "Rovann2", Email = "Teste2@Teste.com" });           
        lista.Add(new Pessoa() { Nome = "Rovann3", Email = "Teste3@Teste.com" });

        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Nome";
        listBox1.DataSource = lista;


    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Select one item";


        //1

        if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            label1.Text = ((Pessoa)listBox1.SelectedItem).Email;
        }

        //2

        Pessoa p = lista.Find(x => x.Nome == listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        if (p != null)
            label1.Text = p.Email;


        //3

        if (listBox1.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            label1.Text = lista[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Email;

    }
```

Comment: Wow! Really nice way of doing it! I didn't think of it. So many ways to fill the labels, haha. I also didn't know about .DisplayMember and .DataSource. That's really neat! Thank you!

Comment: Which way do you think is the best for performance on the label text? Is there much difference between them you think?

Comment: The first way, because it already directly selects the listbox object, however it will only work if I set the datasource as I did.

Comment: You will only notice performance difference in the second form, and if it is a very large list. Otherwise, imperceptible.