# Bind the SelectedItem of a ListBox to another ListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, listbox

I have this model:

```
class Car
{
  string CrewNickname { get; set; }
  Líst<string> RacersNames { get; set; }
}

class StartingField
{
  List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}
```

What I need is to display cars in one ListBox and when I click on any car, to display names of its racers in the second ListBox.
I also need to be able to add/remove cars and add/remove/edit racers.

I haven't found any suitable tutorial or question, but I think this must be possible to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

- Use two BindingSource objects to link each Car in the list to its list of `RacersNames`
- Add a Property used to show each Car name in the first ListBox (the `CarID` Property is there just to show the use of `ValueMember`)
- You need public Properties, of course.

```
BindingSource bsCars = null;
BindingSource bsRacers = null;
StartingField startingField = null;

public class Car
{
    public Car(string carName, int carID) { CarName = carName; CarID = carID; }
    public string CarName { get; }
    public int CarID { get; }
    public List<string> RacersNames { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}

public class StartingField
{
    public List<Car> Cars { get; } = new List<Car>();
}
```

Then initialize the source of data and set the DataSource of the BindingSource objects and the ListBoxes.
Since the second BindingSource is linked to the `RacersNames` property of the first BindingSource, when you select a car name in the first ListBox, the second BindingSource will update its content and, as a consequence, the ListBox bound to it will show the list of `RacersNames` related to the new selection.

Elements can be added or removed from both lists.

You can add this code to the `Load` event (or `OnLoad()` override) of a Form.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
{
    startingField = new StartingField();
    var c1 = new Car("Car1", 1) { RacersNames = { "Racer1", "Racer2", "Racer3" } };
    var c2 = new Car("Car2", 2) { RacersNames = { "Racer4", "Racer5", "Racer6" } };
    var c3 = new Car("Car3", 3) { RacersNames = { "Racer7", "Racer8", "Racer9" } };
   
    startingField.Cars.AddRange(new[] { c1, c2, c3});

    bsCars = new BindingSource(startingField.Cars, "");
    bsRacers = new BindingSource(bsCars, "RacersNames");

    lstCars.DisplayMember = "CarName";
    lstCars.ValueMember = "CarID";
    lstCars.DataSource = bsCars;
    lstRacers.DataSource = bsRacers;
}
```

To add or remove `Car` objects, or add/remove elements from the current `RacersNames` list, use the linked BindingSources.
You can add/remove elements from the underlying BindingList (the list created internally).

<sub>See the animation to determine what Buttons this code maps to</sub>

```
private void btnAddCar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var newCar = startingField.Cars.Count + 1;
    bsCars.Add(new Car($"Car{newCar}", newCar)
    {
        RacersNames = { "Racer10", "Racer11", "Racer12" }
    });
}

private void btnAddRider_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bsRacers.Add("New Rider");
}

private void btnRemoveRider_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstRacers.SelectedIndex < 0) return;
    bsRacers.Remove(lstRacers.GetItemText(lstRacers.SelectedItem));
}
```

This is how it works:

[image: BindingSource Linked ListBoxES]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the OnSelectedIndex method for the first listbox, that raises the SelectedValueChanged event. Then populate the second listbox based on the selected index of the first listbox.

Comment: Are you sure this ensures me ability to update items in second listbox?

Comment: By 'update' I meant 'edit'. Are you sure that if I add/remove/edit item in second listbox, startingField would be updated as well? Could you, please, provide a piece of code? I'm also not sure what exactly does 'populate' mean.